# Django: Test confusion

Tags: django, unit-testing

In the unit tests that I wrote, I provide a test fixture for each TestCase. However, I keep getting duplicate (IntegrityError) when it runs in the test suite.

So, I am wondering, isn't the database supposed to be created and populated at the beginning of each TestCase and after each test has be executed in that TestCase so that I can provide a different fixture for each TestCase?

---

Edit: added test code

```
class DashboardTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['initial.json']

    def setUp(self):
        u = User(username='su')
        u.save()
        self.name = "Test Dashboard"
        self.slug = "test-dashboard"
        self.description = "Test Description"
        self.fiscal_year = "2011"
        self.region = "Test Region"
        self.review_date = "2010-08-01"
        self.date_completed = "2009-03-15"
        self.prepared_by = "Test User"
        self.dashboard = Dashboard(name=self.name, description=self.description, fiscal_year=self.fiscal_year,
                                    region=self.region, review_date=self.review_date, date_completed=self.date_completed,
                                    prepared_by=self.prepared_by)
        self.dashboard.save()

    def testDashboardName(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.name, self.name)
    def testDashboardDescription(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.description, self.description)
    def testDashboardFiscalYear(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.fiscal_year, self.fiscal_year)
    def testDashboardRegion(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.region, self.region)
    def testDashboardReviewDate(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.review_date, self.review_date)
    def testDashboardDateCompleted(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.date_completed, self.date_completed)
    def testDashboardPreparedBy(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.prepared_by, self.prepared_by)
    def testDashboardSlug(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard.slug, self.slug)
    def testDashboardSlugClash(self):
        # Create another dashboard with exactly the same name.
        self.dashboard2 = Dashboard(name='Test Dashboard')
        self.dashboard2.save()
        self.assertEqual(self.dashboard2.slug, 'test-dashboard1')
```

And the traceback:

```
Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '/Users/Eric/Documents/DjangoProjects/MMR/../MMR/dashboard/fixtures'.
Problem installing fixture '/Users/Eric/Documents/DjangoProjects/MMR/../MMR/dashboard/fixtures/initial_data.json': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py", line 169, in handle
    obj.save(using=using)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/serializers/base.py", line 165, in save
    models.Model.save_base(self.object, using=using, raw=True)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 501, in save_base
    rows = manager.using(using).filter(pk=pk_val)._update(values)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 491, in _update
    return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(None)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 861, in execute_sql
    cursor = super(SQLUpdateCompiler, self).execute_sql(result_type)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 727, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 86, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-i386/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry 'dashboard-action' for key 'app_label'")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I am wondering, isn't the database supposed to be created and populated at the beginning of each TestCase

The *database* is only created once - at the beginning of the test run. That is, when you execute `./manage.py test`. Test fixtures are loaded and removed respectively before and after executing *each test method*. This means that all of your fixtures are loaded to the database before each test method is executed. The database is dropped *after all tests have been run*.

> I keep getting duplicate (IntegrityError) when it runs in the test suite

Without seeing the code the first place I would check would be `initial_data` if it exists. `Initial_data` is loaded to the database at the end of `syncdb` and this happens before testing starts. Make sure that your `initial_data` does not load any conflicting data.

Second place to look would be other fixtures, especially if you are using more than one fixture file per test class.

**Update**

```
Problem installing fixture '/Users/Eric/Documents/DjangoProjects/MMR/../MMR/dashboard/fixtures/initial_data.json':
```

It seems that the error occurs *even before* the fixture (`initial.json`) is loaded. There is most likely something inside `initial_data.json` that is duplicated and thereby violates database integrity.

This is how I'd go about troubleshooting:

```
"Duplicate entry 'dashboard-action' for key 'app_label'"
```

1. Identify which model/table has a constraint that matches `app_label`
2. Go through `initial_data.json` and find out if there exist two rows with the same value for `app_label`.
3. Remove one of them and try again.

On a side note I would suggest renaming the test fixture to something else. It is easy to get confused between `initial.json` and `initial_data.json`. Unless you meant to use `initial_data.json` of course. In that case the `fixtures = ...` line is redundant and can be removed as `initial_data.json` will be loaded anyway.

**Update 2**

After smugly giving advice and patting myself on the back I came upon this [Django bug](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/3591). I am digging up more dirt on it. Will update again after I find more.

Comment: @Eric: Can you remove `django.contrib.contenttypes` from your `INSTALLED_APPS` and try again? I just want to verify a theory.

Comment: We just discovered a bug in one of our production applications. I am working to get that fixed and then will return to this. Thanks. :)